# What use is font-size-adjust: auto in CSS3?

Tags: css, fonts, w3c, font-size

I try to wrap my head around the `auto` property in CSS 3's [`font-size-adjust`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-adjust-prop). The spec says:

> Behaves just like `<number>`, except the number used is the aspect value calculated by user agents for the first font in the list of fonts defined for the initial value of the ‘font-family’ property. Effectively this is the default font used when ‘font-family’ is not otherwise specified.
>
> Authors can use this value to specify that font size should be normalized across fonts based on the x-height without the need to specify the aspect ratio explicitly.

In my narrowed little world I thought, `font-size-adjust` is necessary, when your first choice of font doesn't load. Then you can adapt the size of the fallback font.

Now, how does the browser *calculate the aspect value for a non-existing font*? If it doesn't and isn't intended to, where did I take the wrong turn and what does `auto` really do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression “the first font in the list of fonts defined for the initial value of the ‘font-family’ property” means the browser’s primary default font, typically (but of course not necessarily) Times New Roman. “Initial value” is something defined for every property in CSS specifications. It is usually browser-independent, but for `font-family`, it has explicitly been defined to be defined by the browser.

So the `auto` value in this case means the aspect ratio of that default font.

Comment: So `auto` says basically: "If you can load `fancyfont123`, apply the font-size-adjust aspect ratio of the browser's default font choice to it." Is that right? Or put it another way: `auto` works "the other way round" than specifying a number in that it manipulates *all but the fallback font* while a number manipulates the fallback fonts, if they are used instead of `fancyfont123`.

Comment: No, `font-size-adjust` causes the font size to be adjusted with a factor equaling the aspect ratio of the browser’s default font divided by the aspect ratio of the font used (whether it is a font specified in your list or something else).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I guess, that's what I meant (in a complicated way). In the spec's formula `c  =  ( a / a' ) s` we talk about `a`. If I specify a `<number>`, I set an `a` (let's call it `a_number`) explicitly to match my personal choice of font. If I say `auto`, the browser determines an `a` (`a_auto`) by all it got, which is the aspect value of the default font. Usually `a_auto != a_number`, so the rendering will be different. However, in both cases you end up with a consistent x-height, which was the aim of the whole thing. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. I don't quite see *why* one would use the `auto` value, though.

Comment: That was exactly my problem in the first place :-) Thanks again for the explanation!

Comment: If author wants to honor visitor's default font size (usually a good idea) and have readable x-height with a custom font, the `font-size-adjust: auto` is the only way to go. Try using something like "Monsieur La Doulaise" (http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Monsieur+La+Doulaise) for body text without using `font-size-adjust: auto`. Unfortunately, the browser support for value `auto` is currently really poor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user sets his default UA font to have the perfect legibility for himself, then any FSA:auto font would match that. In CSS the presumption is that the user (not the designer) is ultimately right, so this just goes along with that.